# Getting error on [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^-[TiBlob _formatReader]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, titanium, media, video-processing, titanium-modules

I am Getting following error on exporting the video using
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^

Error:

-[TiBlob _formatReader]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I am using the Titanium Module. I am sending video from application to the module.

Any Idea on this, as I have not get any clue for this. Thanks in Advance for the expert advice.

Comment: This is working fine, when I get the video from module itself. The error is occuring only when I setting the module instance from application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am passing the video file as "event.media" from the Titanium Application. Now I am getting "event.media" to the custom Titanium Module as object of TiBlob.

```
videoObj= [[TiBlob alloc]init];
```

After initializing the videoObj, get the value from application to videoObj. Using videoObj(TiBlob) I just initialize AVAsset. That resolve the issue for me.

```
NSURL *url= [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:videoObj.path];
source = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey]];
```